# vscode not connecting to multiple gitlab accounts using their respective ssh keys

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab, vscode-remote

So for windows, I see the default ssh client config supposed to be placed at `C:\Users\Admin\.ssh\config` and I use the same, also I am the Admin user.

I added the following ssh client side config:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> type .\.ssh\config
Host gc
    HostName gitlab.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company_gitlab
Host gp
    HostName gitlab.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_personal
```

I tested it from Powershell and it is [working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65513429/problems-connecting-vscode-through-ssh-to-gitlab) for both my company and personal GitLab accounts using their respective ssh keys.

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> ssh -T git@gc
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\Admin/.ssh/company_gitlab':
Welcome to GitLab, @johnwilson!

PS C:\Users\Admin> ssh -T git@gp
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\Admin/.ssh/gitlab_personal':
Welcome to GitLab, @jwilson!
```

But when it comes to the vscode, when I try to push or pull changes to the remote repository, the following error shows up for both the company and personal GitLab accounts.

```
> git push -u gc master
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

> git push -u gp master
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I tried the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775626/ssh-config-with-multiple-keys-for-multiple-gitlab-user-accounts) as well

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\ownCloud\Company\GitLab\userlist> git remote add origin git@gc:company/infra_code/userlist.git
PS C:\Users\Admin\ownCloud\Company\GitLab\userlist> git remote -v
origin  git@gc:company/infra_code/userlist.git (fetch)
origin  git@gc:company/infra_code/userlist.git (push)

PS C:\Users\Admin\ownCloud\Company\GitLab\userlist> git ls-remote origin
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\Admin/.ssh/company_gitlab':
611b36ef47056773c288499cb6974d8671196d78        HEAD
611b36ef47056773c288499cb6974d8671196d78        refs/heads/master
```

I am confused, so vscode does not pick the default ssh client config `C:\Users\Admin\.ssh\config` on windows ?.

Or am I missing something?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH config with multiple keys for multiple gitlab user accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775626/ssh-config-with-multiple-keys-for-multiple-gitlab-user-accounts)

Comment: Unfortunately, not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the remote URL associated with the remote named 'gc'

```
cd C:\path\to\gc\repo
git remote -v
```

If the URL starts with `git@gitlab.com:...`, it won't use the `~/.ssh/config` file, and its `gc` entry.

Change it with the proper URL

```
git remote set-url gc gc:<me>/<myrepo>
```

Then VSCode will pick up the right entry, assuming is is running as User `Admin`.

---

The [OP JohnW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3692455/johnw) confirms in [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53685346#53685346):

> I added an SSH key without a passphrase, which is working for vscode.   So this is bug with VSCode cannot connect with ssh key with passphrase?

You need to make sure ssh-agent is activated first.
See "[Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#adding-or-changing-a-passphrase)"

Once the SSH agent is launched (and your private SSH keys passphrase cached in it), you can launch VSCode. It should work then.

Comment: Yeh, I see it is already done, still not working for vscode.

Comment: @JohnW Do you mean the remote URL is actually `gc:<me>/<myrepo>`, and is named gc?

Comment: Yes. 
`PS C:\Users\Admin\ownCloud\Company\GitLab\userlist> git remote -v`
Output:
`gc      gc:company/infra_code/userlist.git (fetch)`
`gc      gc:company/infra_code/userlist.git (push)`

Comment: @JohnW In command li,e, as user admi, would a `git  ls-remote gc` work? (it should just return the list of remote branches, without fetching anything: a good lightweight test)

Comment: Yes, CLI always work, only issue with vscode.
`PS C:\Users\Admin\ownCloud\Company\GitLab\userlist> git ls-remote gc`
`Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\Admin/.ssh/company_gitlab':`
`611b36ef47056773c288499cb6974d8671196d78        HEAD`
`611b36ef47056773c288499cb6974d8671196d78        refs/heads/master`

Comment: @JohnW Is VSCode running with the same user Admin? Would a CLI from a VSCode terminal work too (`git ls-remote gc`)

Comment: Yes, Vscode works as the same windows user. Basically, the above CLI result from the vscode provided terminal :) 
It is super weird why vscode cannot work when it comes to the UI, but terminal and git cli works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240281/discussion-between-vonc-and-johnw).